# Oracle Join Between with Interval Times of Minutes

Tags: sql, oracle, time, setinterval

I have some problems with joining tables with different date interval by minutes.

#### Example :

table1

```
ID  Modules    Timestamp
1   Delivered  02-FEB-2020 08:24:45
1   Read       02-FEB-2020 08:27:50
1   Delivered  03-FEB-2020 09:24:45
1   Read       03-FEB-2020 10:00:50
2   Delivered  03-FEB-2020 09:28:10
2   Read       03-FEB-2020 09:30:11
```

#### Question:

is there any way to make the data become like this?

```
 ID  Modules1    Timestamp1            Modules2   Timestamp2
 1   Delivered   02-FEB-2020 08:24:45  Read       02-FEB-2020 08:27:50
 1   Delivered   03-FEB-2020 09:24:45
 1   Read        03-FEB-2020 10:00:50
 2   Delivered   03-FEB-2020 09:28:10  Read       03-FEB-2020 09:30:11
```

#### Goal:

so if someone read during 5 minutes then it will join, if not the data will remain same.

Comment: Post it on something like SQLFiddle.com  and  with a schema and some sample data. Then, include a link in your question. That way, you are more likely to get a reply. Also, the ID of the Module is that significant in your join too? Without that, the question is ambiguous.

Comment: Couple of ways I'd try: 1) use subqueries to split them into only-delivered and only-read then full outer join on id and read.time between delivered.time and delivered.time+5min, and case when delivered values are null use read values instead. 2) use lag/ lead analytical function partition by ID to look around the current row; case when current row is delivered then 'y' as keep , case when next row is read and within 5 mins tack those read column values onto it. Case when current row is read and previous row more than 5 mins before then 'y' as keep else 'n', then wrap all in a WHERE keep='y'

Answer (score 1):

I interpret this as a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  Each "island" either starts with a lag of 5 minutes on a "Read" or any row with "Delivered".

```
with tgrp as (
      select t.*,
             sum(case when modules = 'Delivered' or
                           prev_timestamp < timestamp - interval '5' minute
                        then 1 else 0
                   end) over (partition by id order by timestamp) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(timestamp) over (partition by id order by timestamp) as prev_timestamp
            from t
           ) t
      )
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then module end) as module1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then timestamp end) as timestamp1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then module end) as module2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then timestamp end) as timestamp2
from (select tgrp.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, grp order by timestamp) as seqnum
      from tgrp
     ) tgrp
group by id, grp;
```

EDIT:

I think a simpler method is to put the data together using `lead()` and then filter and adjust the final values:

```
select t.id, t.module, t.timestamp,
       (case when t.next_module = 'Read' and
                  t.next_timestamp < t.timestamp + interval '5' minute
             then t.next_module
        end) as module2,
       (case when t.next_module = 'Read' and
                  t.next_timestamp < t.timestamp + interval '5' minute
             then t.next_timestamp
        end) as timestamp2
from (select t.*,
             lead(module) over (partition by id order by timestamp) as next_module,
             lead(timestamp) over (partition by id order by timestamp) as next_timestamp
      from t
     ) t
where module = 'Delivery' or
      (next_timestamp > timestamp + interval '5' minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do self join to achieve the desired result as following:

```
With cte as 
(Select t.*, 
       Row_number() over (partition by id, modules order by timestamp) as rn
  From your_table t)
Select t1.*, 
       case when t1.modules = 'delivered' and t1.timestamp + interval '5' minute <= t2.timestamp 
            then t2.timestamp 
       end as timestamp2
       From cte t1 
       left join cte t2
       On (t1.rn = t2.rn and t2.modules = 'read')
       Left join cte3 
       On (t1.rn = t3.rn and t3.modules = 'delivered')
Where t1.modules = 'delivered' or t3.timestamp + interval '5' minute > t2.timestamp
```

Cheers!!